# Multi Language and Multi Theme Wordpress

Tags: multi-language

I want to develop a wordpress site where i have two languages "English" and "Arabic". When i select a "Arabic" Language then the theme turns to RTL Mode.
Can anyone share an idea.?

For Multi language i will use Polylang.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Have you read [the codex entry on RTL support](https://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support)?

Comment: @mmm how can i load a RTL css file when i select Arabic language.?

Comment: I would use [MultilingualPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/), each language is its own site of a [WordPress multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) setup. In my opinion it is the best language plugin out there anyway. You then can just setup two themes, for each site one, one with RTL support and one without. That is it.